# How to create a nested list using for loop

Tags: python, nested-lists

I've created a nested list which I need to apply further transformations to:

```
for i in range(len(img_list)):
    image = cv.imread(img_list[i]['name'])
    gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_list[i]['faces'] = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.4)
    print(img_list[i]['faces'])
```

The results contain multiple lists of xy coordinates in the form of (x1, y1, width, height) whereby each sublist represents faces detected using openCV and each list represents a picture (4 pictures in total).

```
[[3109 1698  354  354]
 [1959 1867  253  253]
 [1132 1978  253  253]
 [2556 1965  181  181]
 [1165 2018  181  181]
 [1682 2035  181  181]
 [2632 3020  354  354]]
[[ 494 1365  129  129]
 [2065 2499   47   47]
 [2511 2416   66   66]]
[[2094  702  129  129]
 [ 657 1542  181  181]]
[[1805 1405  181  181]
 [1938 1781   66   66]]
```

I need to transform this by converting the coordinates to x1, y1, x2, y2.

I tried the following code to convert the coordinates, but need to alter it so that the original list (picture)>>sub-list (face coordinates) format is maintained.

```
for i in range(len(img_list)):
    img_list[i]['crop_areas'].append(rec3)
    for face in range(len(img_list[i]['faces'])):
        rec = img_list[i]['faces'][face].tolist()
        rec2 = (rec[0],rec[1],rec[0]+rec[2],rec[1]+rec[3])
        rec2 = list(rec2)
        rec3.append(rec2)
    img_list[i]['crop_areas']
```

Comment: Where's the zero coordinate for this coordinate system? What's the direction for increasing x,y axis for the coordinate system you are talking about?

Comment: Hi there. The original coordinate system (x, y, w, h)  and y denote the upper left hand point for the image and the width and height represent the bounding box.

Comment: Can you add expected output for a single sublist?

Comment: Hi There.

Ideally the expected output is the following. I am trying to convert the original coordinate system to x1, y1, x2, y2

[[3109, 1698, 3463, 2052]
[1959, 1867, 2212, 2120]
[1132, 1978, 1385, 2231]
[2556, 1965, 2737, 2146]
[1165, 2018, 1346, 2199]
[1682, 2035, 1863, 2216]
[2632, 3020, 2986, 3374]
[494, 1365, 623, 1494]]
[[2065, 2499, 2112, 2546]
[2511, 2416, 2577, 2482]]
[[2094, 702, 2223, 831]
[657, 1542, 838, 1723]]
[[1805, 1405, 1986, 1586]
[1938, 1781, 2004, 1847]]

Comment: Are you sure your example is correct? If x1 = 3109 and w = 354 then I would expect x2 = 3462 not x2 = 3463. I.e. x2 = x1 + w - 1. Similar for y2. Assuming x2 and y2 are the corners of the bottom right corner. If you have a 1x1 picture, x2 = x1 not x2 = x1 + 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for all four lists of lists.

```py
givenList
[[3109, 1698, 354, 354],
 [1959, 1867, 253, 253],
 [1132, 1978, 253, 253],
 [2556, 1965, 181, 181],
 [1165, 2018, 181, 181],
 [1682, 2035, 181, 181],
 [2632, 3020, 354, 354]]
```

```py
[[item[0], item[1], item[2]+item[0], item[3]+item[1]] for item in givenList]  #It means (x, y, x+w, y+h)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
[[3109, 1698, 3463, 2052],
 [1959, 1867, 2212, 2120],
 [1132, 1978, 1385, 2231],
 [2556, 1965, 2737, 2146],
 [1165, 2018, 1346, 2199],
 [1682, 2035, 1863, 2216],
 [2632, 3020, 2986, 3374]]
```

You can use the same list comprehension for the remaining three lists.